# Created apt-mirror but cannot browse to it from localhost/ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, server, apt, apache2, apt-mirror

I created an apt-mirror on Ubuntu Server 16.04 for the purpose of running an offline apt server for local ubuntu clients in the office. I pulled down the latest xenial debs from the main archive, installed apache2, created my symbolic links to the directories but when I try to browse to http://localhost/ubuntu, I get nothing. I can browse to localhost directly and I get the Apache2 splash page, but I can't view the repository subdirectories.

Steps taken:

```
$apt-get install apt-mirror
$su - apt-mirror /etc/apt/mirror.list
$apt-get install apache2
$ln -s /var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ /var/www/ubuntu
```

But when I try to browse http://127.0.0.1/ubuntu, I get "Not Found".

Suggestions? What have I missed? From what I understand, it shouldn't be too hard to setup an apt-mirror.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link should be directed created at `/var/www/html/ubuntu`. The default Apache web root directory changed from `/var/www` to `/var/www/html` before the release of Ubuntu 14.04.

So your link creation command should be:

```
ln -s /var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ /var/www/html/ubuntu
```

It may be necessary to restart the apache2 service after making this change.

Comment: There are so many tutorials that still point to the old location, it's an common gotcha to have to avoid.