# Debmirror error

Tags: apt, package-management, mirrors, debmirror

I followed the guide for setting up debmirror from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Debmirror . I changed the files to go to an external drive and set it to download Focal and Hirsute. Debmirror completes without errors but I get an error when I try to point a computer to it but get an error when I try apt-get update.

Error message:
The repository 'http://192.168.1.42/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Where am I going wrong?

Files download to here

```
/mnt/USBHDD/mirrors/ubuntu_repository
├── dists
│   ├── focal
│   ├── focal-security
│   ├── focal-updates
│   ├── hirsute
│   ├── hirsute-security
│   └── hirsute-updates
├── pool
│   ├── main
│   ├── multiverse
│   ├── restricted
│   └── universe
└── project
    └── trace
```

For Apache I symlinked to /var/www/ubuntu
Tree looks the same as above.

Here is my sh script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Arch=         -a      # Architecture. For Ubuntu can be i386, powerpc or amd64.
# sparc, only starts in dapper, it is only the later models of sparc.
# For multiple  architecture, use ",". like "i386,amd64"

arch=amd64,i386

# Minimum Ubuntu system requires main, restricted
# Section=      -s      # Section (One of the following - main/restricted/universe/multiverse).
# You can add extra file with $Section/debian-installer. ex: main/debian-installer,universe/debian-installer,multiverse/debian-installer,restricted/debian-installer


section=main,restricted,universe,multiverse

# Release=      -d      # Release of the system (, focal ), and the -updates and -security ( -backports can be added if desired)
# List of updated releases in: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases
# List of sort codenames used: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/

release=focal,focal-security,focal-updates,hirsute,hirsute-security,hirsute-updates

# Server=       -h      # Server name, minus the protocol and the path at the end
# CHANGE "*" to equal the mirror you want to create your mirror from. au. in Australia  ca. in Canada.
# This can be found in your own /etc/apt/sources.list file, assuming you have Ubuntu installed.

server=archive.ubuntu.com

# Dir=          -r      # Path from the main server, so http://my.web.server/$dir, Server dependant

inPath=/ubuntu

# Proto=        --method=       # Protocol to use for transfer (http, ftp, hftp, rsync)
# Choose one - http is most usual the service, and the service must be available on the server you point at.
# For some "rsync" may be faster.

proto=rsync

# Outpath=              # Directory to store the mirror in
# Make this a full path to where you want to mirror the material.

outPath=/mnt/USBHDD/mirrors/ubuntu_repository

# The --nosource option only downloads debs and not deb-src's
# The --progress option shows files as they are downloaded
# --source \ in the place of --no-source \ if you want sources also.
# --nocleanup  Do not clean up the local mirror after mirroring is complete. Use this option to keep older repository

# Start script

debmirror       -a $arch \
                --no-source \
                --check-gpg \
                --checksums \
                -s $section \
                -h $server \
                -d $release \
                -r $inPath \
```

Comment: Probably you should carefully read again the part about "GPG keyring file" and check what you actually did instead.

Comment: All needed keys have been imported to local trustedkeys.gpg. Also tried it with
export GNUPGHOME=/mnt/USBHDD/mirrors/

Both instances debmirror has no problems but still get the repository errors from apt-get update.

Comment: @ChanganAuto 
I have redone everything verbatim from the guide. I used symlinks to point directories to the external HDD. Repository error still persists. I am at a loss of what else to do. Is the release file being removed some how with cleanup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much web surfing I found the answer to my question.
The problem was with Apache's default location.

Guide has it listed as /var/www/ubuntu

Should be /var/www/**html**/ubuntu

After making that change my mirror is working.

Missing piece to the puzzle was located at:
[Created apt-mirror but cannot browse to it from localhost/ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/876499/created-apt-mirror-but-cannot-browse-to-it-from-localhost-ubuntu)
Props to Arronical